# Moving Site Template (.stp) files to SharePoint 2010

Tags: upgrade, site-template

MOSS Site Template (.stp) files are no longer supported in SharePoint 2010. So how do you import .stp files?

[Isha Kapoor's blog post](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/06/20/moving-site-template-stp-files-to-sharepoint-2010/) describes these steps:

1. First you need to create a site in SharePoint 2007 using your .stp template.
2. Then, backup the database for that site and restore it on SharePoint 2010 environment.
3. After you do that just open up the site and fix any issues (like 12 hive referencing files etc).
4. Now, you can Save this Site (from Settings page -> Save as Template) and it will give you a .wsp solution for the site.

Anyone has any better solution?

Comment: What's your current issue with that method - I think it may be the only supported one at present.

Comment: I have a .stp which contain a list template, I want to use this in SharePoint 2010, but I dont have a wss environment. Of caurse I can download a VPC WSS Image from Microsoft and follow the steps. But I want to investigate if there is another approch for moving .stp files to Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: It doesn't support STP files? Oh really? Then why is it when I create a List then go to the List and choose create template it puts an .STP in the List Template folder? Might want to revisit this.

Comment: List templates and Site templates are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the only way of doing it. A slight variation is to stand up a simple 2007 farm, presumably in a VM, load the .stp and create a site, then do an in-place upgrade to SP2010. Then fix any issues and save the .wsp for the site.

You are effectively doing the same thing, but without having to fiddle around with content databases.

Answer (score 0):

**How to upgrade your custom list templates from WSS 2007 version to SharePoint 2010 version**

Navigate to your top level site collection

Click on the Site Actions -> Site Settings

Click on the List templates under the Galleries section

Click on the template you want to upgrade and Save it. ( it will have an “.stp” file extension )  Let’s use c:\Temp as an example file location we saved this to and Template.stp as the example filename.

Rename that file you saved to a “.cab” file extension ( Rename C:\Temp\Template.stp C:\Temp\Template.cab )

Right-click on the Template.cab and extract the contents

Edit the manifest.xml file and change the ProductVersion element from 3 to 4

Save your change

Repackage the “.stp” file by using the makecab.exe ( c:\windows\system32\makecab.exe c:\Temp\manifest.xml c:\Temp\Template.cab )

Rename C:\Temp\Template.cab C:\Temp\Template.stp

Now upload the new C:\Temp\Template.stp to your List Templates in the Galleries.

Create a new list using the template.