# Upload Site Template (.stp) as Farm solution using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-addin, site-template

I have custom site template file which i got from the SP2007 site as .stp file..

`CustomTemplate.stp`

What i need to do is Deploy this site template to SharePoint 2010 Farm..

I know i can do it from stsadm command.. But i need to do it from Powershell command..

If this is not possible please give me a way to install this site template site collection wise..

Basically im asking replacement for following command with Powershell..

`Stsadm.exe -o addtemplate -filename C:\CustomTemplate.stp -title "Custom Site"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done SharePoint 2010 doesn't support .stp Site Templates only .stp List Templates and .wsp Site Templates.

See TechNet article: [Deploy templates (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607540.aspx)

It says:

> The STP format of a custom site template (.stp file) is deprecated in
>   SharePoint Foundation 2010 and replaced with WSP format site
>   templates. In Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, users can save an
>   existing site as a custom site template. The site template is stored
>   in the database as a model, and users can select the site template as
>   a foundation that defines how to instantiate the site. In SharePoint
>   Foundation 2010, users can save an existing site as a template. The
>   template is saved as a .wsp file in the Solution Gallery of the
>   top-level site in a site collection, where it becomes available for
>   subsite creation on all Web sites in the site collection

See this earlier question on how to upgrade site Templates: [Moving Site Template (.stp) files to SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5986/moving-site-template-stp-files-to-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: Ok.. other than deploying can i upload this to site template gallery by using powershell..

Comment: OK guys.. as you mentioned this is imposible.. So i found a way to run stsadm commands inside powershell.. thank you for your help..

Comment: Well yes. You can add a .stp Site Template using `STSADM -o AddTemplate`, but when you try to use it you'll just get the error message `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation version 3 templates are not supported in this version of the product.`. So even though STSADM lets you add the template it's of no use which is why I wrote that it's not possible.

Comment: Yes.. But from the inside of stp im changing the current sharepoint version and try to upload that in to sharepoint site.. in that case i succeed to add custom template into sharepoint 2010 site.. Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 3):

SP2010 doesn't work with STP files anymore. SharePoint 2010 supports only wsp solutions.

Commad to deploy webtemplate wsp is

> Install-SPWebTemplate -path "C:/webtemplates/test1.wsp" -name "test1"
>   -description "TestWSP" -Confirm:$false